# choosing three adjacent cells from n cells using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let us say that we have $n$ adjacent cells numbered from $1$ to $n$ (eg. $1$ to $12$ for $n=12$).  In how many ways can we choose three adjacent cells?

If $n=3$, we can choose just cell $1,2,3$. Thus ans is $1$.

If $n=4$, we can choose just cell $1,2,3$ or $2,3,4$. Thus ans is $2$.

If $n=5$, ans is $3$.

Is it correct to say that ans is $n-2$?  I just observed this.

Comment: Clearly all that matters is the choice of the first one. What position are possible for the first one ?

Answer (score 2):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

You are correct that the answer is $n - 2$.  The three adjacent cells must start in one of the first $n - 2$ positions so that the third cell falls within the first $n - 2 + 2 = n$ positions.

More generally, the number of ways $k$ adjacent cells can be selected from $n$ cells is $n - k + 1$, provided $n - k + 1 \geq 0$.